# Merging a Branch of a Branch Into Master

Tags: git, merge

I have a situation like this:

```
master
   |
    ---- new-branch-1
               |
                ---- new-branch-1.1
```

Will I be able to merge `new-branch-1.1` back into master directly without any issues, or do I need to merge it into `new-branch-1`, then merge `new-branch-1` into `master`?  I realize I could just "try it and see what happens," but I really don't want to run into issues that could potentailly cripple my codebase.  I have backups of all my repos, but if I accidentally corrupt the original (or cause any sort of issue forces me to delete the local copy) then my backup is no longer a backup and that worries me.

I do use GitHub Desktop for most of my git needs.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the github desktop pull request functionality by running:

```
git push origin new-branch-1.1
```

and then seeing whether your changes will merge in cleanly at the bottom of the page: here is what that looks like for me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Great piece of advice, exactly what I was looking for!